# Running cronjob on specfic hours

Tags: linux, unix, cron

How do i setup a cronjob to run every hour except from 11pm until 1am ?

Because during that time, the system is doing maintenance.

Cheers

Comment: what does this question have to do with c#? I am removing the tag.

Comment: Read the crontab(5) manpage.

Comment: did you checked **man 5 crontab**?

Comment: I did. Obviously i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options:

- Run the job every hour, but have the job itself be a script that checks the current time and immediately exits if it's between 11pm and 1am.
- Specify all 21 hours that it should run:

`0 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 * * *   do_something`

(I *think* I got that right.)

- If the version of `cron` you're using supports it, you can specify a range:

`0 2-22 * * * do_something`

`man 5 crontab` to confirm this.